# Can git push with empty repo path?

Tags: linux, git

I created a user name git. And here's the passwd file:

```
git:x:1001:1001:git:/home/git/test.git:/bin/bash
```

Then created a bared repo named 'test.git'. The full path is '/home/git/test.git'.

If I add the remote like beblow, it will works:

```
git add remote origin git@abc.com:./
```

But I wonder if below will work? Do I need some addition settings in git?

```
git add remote origin git@abc.com
```

Comment: "But I wonder if below will work?" when you tried - did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you want to have your server setup as you suggest - it's certainly not normal.

### git as a bash user is INsecure

if you leave your git config as it is in the question you are relying on trust alone that anyone who has access as git does not do the following:

```
ssh git@abc.com
cd ..
ls -la // have a look
rm -rf test.git // delete git repo
cd / // go have a hack around
etc.
```

### Do it the normal way

Setting up a git server, [is easy](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) - almost trivial.

if you update your `passwd` file so it looks like this:

```
git:x:1001:1001::/home/git:/usr/bin/git-shell
```

Then the user git can do absolutely nothing except perform git commands.

As such you'd then do:

```
git add remote origin git@abc.com:test.git
git pull // etc
```

### git shell is secure

None of these things will work for a user that has git-shell as their login shell:

```
ssh git@abc.com

git remote add another git@abc.com:another.git
git push another // attempting to create a new repo

etc.
```

The only thing it lets you do is effectively pull and push to the remote.